Question on Clayton Copula
The Clayton Copula is defined, for $u=F_X(x)$ and $v=F_Y(y)$ distribution functions, say of two continuous rv's,
$$C_{\rm Clayton} = \Big[\max\{u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta}-1;\,0\}\Big]^{-1/\theta},\quad \theta \in (-1,\infty) \backslash \{0\}.$$
The $0$ value in the $\max$ can only come about if $\theta <0$.
Say this is the case. Then for a subset of $[0,1]^2$, the Copula will also take the value zero. Fine, but the arguments of the Copula, the two distribution functions, do take values, individually, in this subset.
Does this mean that the Clayton Copula with $\theta <0$, is to be used only when we want to reflect that the two rv's have zero probability of being realized jointly in this subset of values in the joint support?

Clayton copula cannot deal with negative relations. You may need to use the inverse of Clatyon, as the parameter of the Clayton copula is positive, and 0 means independence.

@Dr.Statistics I am not sure I understand. I asked about the case of $\theta \in (-1,0)$, that it is my impression that it is accomodated by the Clayton Copula. I didn't say that $\theta <0$ creates negative dependence. What I asked is whether in such a case, the behavior of the Clayton Copula is such that it implies that certain pair of values/joint intervals of the underlying random variables, are treated as having zero probability of occuring.

Hi. Thanks for your comments. If I understand correctly, "Does this mean that the Clayton Copula with θ<0, is to be used only when we want to reflect that the two rv's have zero probability of being realized jointly in this subset of values in the joint support?" The answer is No.

I wasn't fully saisfied with the exchange in the comments, so here are two scattergrams (generated by the conditional Copula method) for the bivariate "Clayton" Copula (in quotes because it appears that this is just another case of Stigler's Law of Eponymy).
The first is with $\theta = -0.5$, the second with $\theta = -0.8$. It is evident (as it already was form the mathematical expressions involved), that when $\theta < 0$, then there is a subset in the joint support of the two variables that is never realized.
So indeed, with $\theta <0$, this Copula reflects "negative dependence" and it is suitable when a subset of the joint probabilities reflected by its arguments do not materialize (in the real world phenomenon that we attempt to model with it).



This is not a regular Clayton copula but a modified one with ∈[−1,∞)∖{0}. Clayton copula can only model lower positive tail dependencies. You may interested in reading this: chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://hal.science/hal-04325664/document.

@Dr.Statistics Indeed. It is how I have defined the Copula in my original post already, extended to allow for this negative interval for theta. Thanks for the link, really interesting.

Thanks for your comment and clarification of your idea.
